# updating updatepanel on checkbox check ( which has client events and is in other updatepanel)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in asp.net application. I have a checkbox and three textboxes inside an `updatepanel`. I have another updatepanel. I am using Jquery to hide show the textboxes. I want to update the second updatepanel contents as well on first updatepanel's checkbox check/uncheck ( which already has client events) How can I do this ?

I don't want to use `__doPostBack('__Page', 'MyCustomArgument');` because it will postback whole page.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding your requirements but you can always force the second update panel to refresh from the code behind

```
SecondPanelId.Update();
```

I could have missed something of course

To force update from javscript then I would try

```
function forceAJAXPostback()
{
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
    prm._doPostBack('btnIntheUpdatePanel','');
}
```

I know you said not `_doPostBack` - but because you are specifying the button within the update panel it should do the partial postback you require. If there isn't a button then put one on and hide it with css i.e. `display:none`

This is a [good explanation](http://encosia.com/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/) of the technique.

You would also need to ensure that the button is specified as an async trigger in the updatepanel markup

```
<asp:UpdatePanel> 
<!-- rest of panel -->
<Triggers>         
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnIntheUpdatePanel" EventName="Click" />         
</Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: @Carb When I have added client side event to checkbox, its server side checkchange event will never be called. Do I need to reload the second update panel using the js ?

Comment: could this work in js? <%=SecondPanelId.ClientID%>.Update();  Never tried it. The same principle works with button clicks

Comment: I am not sure if this will work. I am trying to use it. let c If it works

Comment: Hi Crab: I used this:  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm._doPostBack('UpdatePanel2', ''); but it is doing full postback